# Django-celery task being serviced by wrong running instance

Tags: django, rabbitmq, django-celery

I've got a Django app that uses django-celery with a rabbitmq backend. We have a test machine where different users are running the same Django app in their own accounts (each listening on a different port), but all are using identical settings.py files, and therefore the same rabbitmq credentials, to connect celery to the back-end. (Note that they're each using a different sqlite database for the db backend).

I just discovered that we may be getting "crosstalk" among the django-celery tasks, that a task request from the django app in user A's account might be being serviced by a celery task running in user B's account.

What's the simplest way to configure things to avoid this problem? Do I need to create separate rabbitmq accounts and/or vhosts for each user? Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to have separate vhosts for each environment. You could still share the same RabbitMQ user.

Comment: what about my case? can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041596/celery-with-multiple-django-sites