# Celery with multiple django sites

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have a one django backend for few customer's sites:

```
my_proj
    |- my_proj
        |- __init__.py
        |- settings.py
        |- settings_development.py
        |- settings_production_1.py
        |- settings_production_2.py
        |- settings_production_3.py
    |- my_app_1
    |- my_app_2
    ...
```

**settings_production_1.py:**

```
from settings import *

DEBUG = False
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'customer_1_db',
        'USER': 'some_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'some_passw',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/customer_1'
```

Each site is a separate proccess managed by supervisord and uses separate database. Also I have a redis on a separate server.

I need some celery background tasks with database access.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I can run multiple celery workers. I can do that from console

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_proj.settings_production_2
$ /home/.../my_vitrual_env/bin/celery -A my_proj worker -l info
```

But I can't run it from supervisord

```
[program:celery2]
directory=/home/.../my_proj
command=/home/.../my_vitrual_env/bin/celery -A asl worker -l info
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_proj.settings_production_2
...
```

Comment: You may need to write an individual task for each site because each site uses a different database and everything.

Comment: Individual task-file or individual tasks inside one tasks.py?

Comment: Individual task. So each task you have will be written 3 times and in each one you will specify the different db to read/write from. Another not cost effective solution is to have 3 worker instances each running on a specific settings file. Easier to implement, but both solutions are horrible to manage.

Comment: @devdob How can I run worker instance with a specific settings file?

Comment: Celery.py looks for an environment variable called `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or defaults to your normal settings.py file specified, look at the line where it says `os.environ.setdefault(...)`. So on each server you can set this environment variable to the settings you want it to run on.

Answer (score 1):

You configure an app for your project .  e.g.:

```
    my_proj
      | - my_proj
        |- __init__.py
        |- celery.py
        |- settings.py
        |- settings_development.py
        |- settings_production_1.py
        |- settings_production_2.py
        |- settings_production_3.py
```

etc.

In the celery.py you configure the celery app from [the appropriate settings object](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) by setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable and use that to load the appropriate settings.

And then in supervisord, you give each site its own celery by specifying the start line as `celery multi -A my_proj` and with the correct `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable.

Comment: So, I need to place settings_production_1.py, settings_production_2.py and settings_production_3.py in a separate folders and put in each folder a celery.py with proper DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Comment: You can do that.  Or alternatively you can just set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable e.g., DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="my_profj.settings_development" in supervisord

Comment: @maksymov:  did you try with multi or worker or both?

Comment: Okay, in general, when starting celery from supervisord or systemd, you'll have to use multi to detach the worker.  You'll also want to set up an application user that celery runs as and you can specify that using `--uid`